# Fastest Way to count all-TRUE rows of a LogicalMatrix R / C++ / Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, performance, matrix, rcpp

#### I need to count the number of rows in a LogicalMatrix that are all `TRUE`.

*Because I need to be able to do this 1 - 2500 million times on a relatively regular basis speed actually really matters:*

#### My current best:

The most efficient / fastest single-process way I've figured how to do this is in the how many Rcpp function (`hm2`).

My limited profiling abilities show me that the vast majority of the time is spent in doing the `if(r_tll == xcolls){...`. I can't seem to think of a different algorithm that would be faster ( I have tried the break out of the loop as soon as a `FALSE` is found and it is much slower).

#### details that can be assumed:

I can assume that:

1. The matrix will always have fewer than 10 million rows.
2. All the output matrices from upstream will have the same number of cols (for a given session/process/thread).
3. There will never be more than 2326 cols per matrix.

#### minimal example:

```r
m <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),50000*10, replace = T),ncol = 10L)
head(m)
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

```c++
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
int hm(const LogicalMatrix& x){
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}
```

I don't understand why, but on my machine if I bake in the number of cols it is faster (if someone could explain why this is it would be great too):

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int hm2(const LogicalMatrix& x){
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  // const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(size_t col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == 10){
      n_all_true += 1;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}
```

#### timing:

```
microbenchmark(hm(m), hm2(m), times = 1000)
#>  Unit: microseconds
#>   expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#>  hm(m) 597.828 599.0995 683.3482 605.397 643.8655 1659.711  1000
#> hm2(m) 236.847 237.6565 267.8787 238.748 253.5280  683.221  1000
```

Comment: Have you tried multithreading?

Comment: @JamesMoore I can dispatch data to different threads, compute the logical matrix based on input data and then compute this yes -- but this is a test case; need to generate say 100M matrices per thread)...essentially the size of the question we can ask depends on how efficient I can make this step (the alg that generates such a matrix is about 100x faster) and so this is the bottle neck. In dream land this would be on the order of 100x faster than my current solution on a single thread. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Regarding your question about why this - "if I bake in the number of cols it is faster" - is true, most likely it has to do with the fact that since the number of columns is a compile time constant, the compiler can incorporate this into its optimization strategy. This is not possible in the first case (the `hm` function), where `xcols` must be determined at run time.

Comment: If you know that you will have a constant number of rows too, that will save even more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your function, and the output from compiling it via `cppFunction`:

```
require(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int hm(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}')
# file.*.cpp: In function ‘int hm(const LogicalMatrix&)’:
# file.*.cpp:12:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
#    for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
#                              ^
# file.*.cpp:14:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
#      for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
#                                ^
```

Note the warnings. I can get a bit of an improvement by using `int` instead of `size_t` for both `row` and `col`. Other than that, I can't find much room for improvement.

And here's my code, benchmarks, and reproducible example:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(microbenchmark)

cppFunction('int hm_jmu(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}')

hm3 <- function(m) {
  nc <- ncol(m)
  sum(rowSums(m) == nc)
}

set.seed(21)
m <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),50000*10, replace = T),ncol = 10L)
microbenchmark(hm(m), hm3(m), hm_jmu(m), times=1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq   median        uq       max neval
#      hm(m)  578.844  594.1460  607.357  636.4410   858.347  1000
#     hm3(m) 6389.014 6452.9595 6476.197 6735.5465 33720.870  1000
#  hm_jmu(m)  409.920  415.0395  424.401  449.0075   650.127  1000
```

Comment: Nice spotting -- I don't get those warnings (see my answer); do you have some flags set / another version of Rcpp?

Comment: @npjc: I have the `-Wall` flag set.

Comment: @hannahheres: I also found that, once there were more than a hundred or so columns, it was faster to use an algorithm that would `break;` the loop over columns when the first `FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

Can go 30% faster still with OpenMP (which I now see is against the question which requests single thread solutions), and minimal code changes, at least on my 4 core Xeon. I have a feeling that a logical AND reduction may do better but will leave that for another day:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

m_rows <- 10L
m_cols <- 50000L
rebuild = FALSE

cppFunction('int hm(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}', rebuild = rebuild)

hm3 <- function(m) {
  nc <- ncol(m)
  sum(rowSums(m) == nc)
}

cppFunction('int hm_jmu(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}', rebuild = rebuild)

macroExpand <- function(NCOL) {
  paste0('int hm_npjc(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
  int r_ttl = 0;
  for(int col = 0; col < ',NCOL,'; col++) {
  r_ttl += x(row,col);
  }
  if(r_ttl == ',NCOL,'){
  n_all_true++;
  }
  }
  return n_all_true;
  }')
}

macroExpand_omp <- function(NCOL) {
  paste0('int hm_npjc_omp(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:n_all_true)
  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
  int r_ttl = 0;
  for(int col = 0; col < ',NCOL,'; col++) {
  r_ttl += x(row,col);
  }
  if(r_ttl == ',NCOL,'){
  n_all_true++;
  }
  }
  return n_all_true;
  }')
}

cppFunction(macroExpand(m_rows), rebuild = rebuild)
cppFunction(macroExpand_omp(m_rows),  plugins = "openmp", rebuild = rebuild)

cppFunction('int hm_omp(const LogicalMatrix& x) {
const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:n_all_true) schedule(static)
  for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 0;
    for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}',  plugins = "openmp", rebuild = rebuild)

# using != as inner loop control - no difference, using pre-increment in n_all_true, no diff, static vs dynamic OpenMP, attempted to direct clang and gcc to unroll loops: didn't seem to work

set.seed(21)
m <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), m_cols * m_rows, replace = T), ncol = m_rows)
print(microbenchmark(hm(m), hm3(m), hm_jmu(m), hm_npjc(m),
                     hm_omp(m), hm_npjc_omp(m),
                     times = 1000))
```

I used GCC 4.9. Clang 3.7 similar results.
Giving:

`Unit: microseconds
           expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval
          hm(m)  614.074  640.9840  643.24836  641.462  642.9920   976.694  1000
         hm3(m) 2705.066 2768.3080 2948.39388 2775.992 2786.8625 43424.060  1000
      hm_jmu(m)  591.179  612.3590  625.84484  612.881  613.8825  6874.428  1000
     hm_npjc(m)   62.958   63.8965   64.89338   64.346   65.0550   144.487  1000
      hm_omp(m)   91.892   92.6050  165.21507   93.758   98.8230 10026.583  1000
 hm_npjc_omp(m)   43.129   43.6820  129.15842   44.458   47.0860 17636.875  1000`

The OpenMP magic is just the inclusion of the `-fopenmp` at compile and link time (taken care of by Rcpp, `plugin="openmp"`), and
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:n_all_true) schedule(static)
In this case, the outer loop is parallelized, and the result is a sum, so the reduction statement tells the compiler to break down the problem, and reduce the sum of each part into a single sum. `schedule(static)` describes how the compiler and/or runtime will allocate the loop between threads. In this case, the width of both inner and outer loops is known, so `static` is preferred; if, say, the inner loop size varied a lot, then `dynamic` might balance the work better between threads.

It is possible to explicitly tell OpenMP how many loop iterations you would like per thread, but it is often better to let the compiler decide.

On a different note, I tried hard to use compiler flags, such as `-funroll-loops` to replace the ugly but fast hard-coding of the inner loop width (which is not a generalized solution to the question). I tested these to no avail: see https://github.com/jackwasey/optimization-comparison

Comment: Great exposure here! Would be even more awesome if you led your answer with how to change to openMP and what it does! (Like walkthrough just hm_omp / hm_npjc_omp

Answer (score 1):

I was very curious as to why 'baking in' what was defined as a `const`
would make any difference; so I played around with this idea.

#### Previously:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
cppFunction('int hm(const LogicalMatrix& x)
            {
            const int xrows = x.nrow();
            const int xcols = x.ncol();
            int n_all_true = 0;

            for(size_t row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
            int r_ttl = 0;
            for(size_t col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
            r_ttl += x(row,col);
            }
            if(r_ttl == 10){
            n_all_true++;
            }
            }
            return n_all_true;
            }')

hm3 <- function(m) {
  nc <- ncol(m)
  sum(rowSums(m) == nc)
}

cppFunction('int hm_jmu(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
  int r_ttl = 0;
  for(int col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
  r_ttl += x(row,col);
  }
  if(r_ttl == xcols){
  n_all_true++;
  }
  }
  return n_all_true;
  }')
```

#### Baking in the number of cols

I'm just taking Joshua's sol'n here but generating the tailored function
by code-gen works well on my machine. **This seems hacky to me but I
thought I would post anyway:**

```
macroExpand <- function(NCOL) {
paste0('int hm_npjc(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
  int r_ttl = 0;
  for(int col = 0; col < ',NCOL,'; col++) {
  r_ttl += x(row,col);
  }
  if(r_ttl == ',NCOL,'){
  n_all_true++;
  }
  }
  return n_all_true;
  }')
}

cppFunction(macroExpand(10L))
```

#### Results:

```
set.seed(21)
m <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),50000*10, replace = T),ncol = 10L)
microbenchmark(hm(m), hm3(m), hm_jmu(m), hm_npjc(m), times=1000)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>        expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
#>       hm(m)  596.808  600.1870  722.5140  629.1750  709.3875  1680.379
#>      hm3(m) 2189.164 2353.6700 2972.1463 2509.4630 2956.7675 49930.471
#>   hm_jmu(m)  574.137  576.5160  678.6475  600.4775  665.2800  2240.988
#>  hm_npjc(m)   81.978   83.1855  102.7646   89.2160  101.0400   380.884
#>  neval
#>   1000
#>   1000
#>   1000
#>   1000
```

I would like to note that I don't really understand why the compiler doesn't optimize to the same solution here; if anyone has insight on this that would be awesome.

#### Provenance

```
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
#>  ui       RStudio (0.99.691)          
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_CA.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Los_Angeles         
#>  date     2015-09-27
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package        * version    date       source                         
#>  clipr            0.1.1      2015-09-04 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  colorspace       1.2-6      2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  devtools         1.9.1      2015-09-11 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  digest           0.6.8      2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  evaluate         0.8        2015-09-18 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  formatR          1.2.1      2015-09-18 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  ggplot2          1.0.1      2015-03-17 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  gtable           0.1.2      2012-12-05 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  htmltools        0.2.6      2014-09-08 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  knitr            1.10.5     2015-05-06 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  magrittr         1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  MASS             7.3-43     2015-07-16 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                 
#>  memoise          0.2.1      2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  microbenchmark * 1.4-2      2014-09-28 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  munsell          0.4.2      2013-07-11 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  plyr             1.8.3      2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  proto            0.3-10     2012-12-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  Rcpp           * 0.12.1     2015-09-10 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  reprex           0.0.0.9001 2015-09-26 Github (jennybc/reprex@1d6584a)
#>  reshape2         1.4.1      2014-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  rmarkdown        0.7        2015-06-13 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  rstudioapi       0.3.1      2015-04-07 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  scales           0.3.0      2015-08-25 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  stringi          0.5-5      2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.2.0)                 
#>  stringr          1.0.0      2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about exploiting the fact that `TRUE` is coerced to `1` for many numeric operators, and then it's all vectorized in functions that are already programmed in C.  E.g.

```
set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50000*10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10L)
sum(rowSums(m) == ncol(m))
## [1] 47

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum(rowSums(m) == ncol(m)))
## Unit: milliseconds
##                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
## sum(rowSums(m) == ncol(m)) 1.715399 1.840763 1.873422 1.861552 1.905841 2.02524   100
```

See [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) Chapter 3.

**Edited answer with direct comparison:**

(here I pasted the two C++ functions into a file called `test.cpp` on my Desktop with the usual Rcpp header info)

```
require(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("~/Desktop/test.cpp")

set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50000*10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10L)

hm3 <- function(m) {
    nc <- ncol(m)
    sum(rowSums(m) == nc)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(hm(m), hm2(m), hm3(m), times = 1000)
## Unit: milliseconds
##   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq        max neval
##  hm(m) 4.996005 5.036732 5.169672 5.089707 5.194580   9.961581  1000
## hm2(m) 5.031222 5.074990 5.228239 5.128106 5.242909  10.109776  1000
## hm3(m) 1.626933 1.878014 2.205195 1.922608 2.014012 226.894190  1000
```

I note here that the reference to R Inferno is not really appropriate since it does not apply to C++ but it's still a mantra to live by. :-)

Comment: can you benchmark against my solution... on my machine this is much slower.

Comment: That's 5-10x slower than the OP's two solutions. And using `.rowSums` is only slightly better than `rowSums`.

Comment: Faster on my system, see direct comparisons I've now added. Using a fast iMac and OS X.

Comment: Hmm that's strange - `hm3` is ~10x slower than `hm2` on my system as well (also an iMac).

Comment: The max time is certainly higher in microbenchmark but with `times = 1000` the median time is going to be very representative. Odd that your results differ though - I cannot explain that one.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this working on a similar problem. We can squeeze a little more performance by initializing `r_ttl` on the first column and eliminating the `if(r_ttl == xcols)` check:

```
# initialize on the first column
cppFunction('int hm2(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = x(row,0);
    for(int col = 1; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl += x(row,col);
    }
    if(r_ttl == xcols){
      n_all_true++;
    }
  }
  return n_all_true;
}')

# use *= to eliminate the if statement
cppFunction('int hm3(const LogicalMatrix& x)
{
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = 1;
    for(int col = 0; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl *= x(row,col);
    }
    n_all_true += r_ttl;
  }
  return n_all_true;
}')

# both modifications
cppFunction('int hm4(const LogicalMatrix& x) {
  const int xrows = x.nrow();
  const int xcols = x.ncol();
  int n_all_true = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < xrows; row++) {
    int r_ttl = x(row,0);
    for(int col = 1; col < xcols; col++) {
      r_ttl *= x(row,col);
    }
    n_all_true += r_ttl;
  }
  return n_all_true;
}')

m <- matrix(sample(c(T,F),50000*10, replace = T),ncol = 10L)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(hm_jmu = hm_jmu(m),
                               hm2 = hm2(m),
                               hm3 = hm3(m),
                               hm4 = hm4(m),
                               check = "equal",
                               times = 1e4)

# Unit: microseconds
#   expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
# hm_jmu 198.3 200.8 218.5362  208.3 212.7 5855.9 10000
#    hm2 169.3 170.9 184.8722  171.4 180.0 5775.4 10000
#    hm3 192.7 196.1 209.7465  196.8 206.3 1056.2 10000
#    hm4 161.9 163.1 176.2370  163.5 171.9 1119.2 10000
```

About a 20% improvement over Joshua Ulrich's even larger improvement.