# Count number of common columns between every row of a dataframe to create an all-vs-all matrix

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

Here is a sample of the data set I have:

rows represent different accessions and columns represent different genes.

```
    gene1   gene2   gene3
1 PRESENT    LOST PRESENT
2 PRESENT PRESENT    LOST
3    LOST PRESENT PRESENT
```

I would like to find the number of the common genes between accessions and create a dataframe accession vs accession as such:

```
> test_self
  1 2 3
1 2 1 1
2 1 2 1
3 1 1 2
```

I used `R` to create this dataframe with the following code

```
gene1  = c("PRESENT", "PRESENT", "LOST")
gene2 = c("LOST", "PRESENT", "PRESENT")
gene3 = c("PRESENT","LOST","PRESENT")
test_PAV <- data.frame (gene1,gene2,gene3)

test_self <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = nrow(test_PAV), nrow = nrow(test_PAV)))
colnames(test_self)<-row.names(test_PAV)
row.names(test_self)<-row.names(test_PAV)

for (rowInQuestion in 1:nrow(test_PAV)){
  for (rowBeingComparedTo in 1:nrow(test_PAV)){
    commonGeneCount <- 0
    for (col in 1:ncol(test_PAV)){
      if(test_PAV[rowInQuestion,col]=='PRESENT'&&test_PAV[rowBeingComparedTo,col]=='PRESENT'){
        commonGeneCount <- commonGeneCount + 1
      }
      test_self[rowInQuestion,rowBeingComparedTo]<-commonGeneCount
    } 
  }
}
```

But I'm well aware that this is a very inefficient solution. First of all, since the upper and the lower triangles are symmetric they don't have to be calculated twice.

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949318/count-common-elements-from-pairwise-rows-with-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe) but there the commonality is across a row but in my case in order to call it a commonality, the same gene (column) has to be 'PRESENT' in both accessions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorizing will give a speed boost for larger datasets:

```
test_PAV <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("PRESENT", "LOST"), 3e4, replace = TRUE), ncol = 150))

fCommonVec <- function(test_PAV) {
  m <- as.matrix(test_PAV) == "PRESENT"
  n <- nrow(m) - 1L
  test_self <- matrix(nrow = nrow(test_PAV), ncol = nrow(test_PAV))
  test_self[lower.tri(test_self)] <- rowSums(m[rep.int(1:n, n:1),] & m[sequence(n:1, 2:nrow(m)),])
  diag(test_self) <- rowSums(m)
  return(test_self)
}
```

Compare with the loop version:

```
fCommonLoop <- function(test_PAV) {
  pavMatrix_transposeBinary <- as.matrix(test_PAV) == "PRESENT"
  pavSelfSimilarity <- matrix(nrow = nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary), ncol = nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary))
  
  for (rowInQuestion in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
    for (rowBeingComparedTo in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
      pavSelfSimilarity[rowInQuestion,rowBeingComparedTo] <- sum(pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowInQuestion,]*pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowBeingComparedTo,])
    }
  }
  
  return(pavSelfSimilarity)
}

test_self <- fCommonVec(test_PAV)
pavSelfSimilarity <- fCommonLoop(test_PAV)

all.equal(test_self[lower.tri(test_self, diag = TRUE)], pavSelfSimilarity[lower.tri(pavSelfSimilarity, diag = TRUE)])
#> [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fCommonVec = fCommonVec(test_PAV),
                               fCommonLoop = fCommonLoop(test_PAV))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   fCommonVec  25.5148  30.6751  36.76842  32.6326  36.0579  76.0979   100
#>  fCommonLoop 215.4542 226.2288 235.84177 229.6783 235.9802 304.1668   100
```

**UPDATE**

For really large datasets, here is a function that iterates by column to cut down on memory usage:

```
test_PAV <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("PRESENT", "LOST"), 267*113000, replace = TRUE), nrow = 267))

fCommonVec2 <- function(test_PAV) {
  m <- as.matrix(test_PAV) == "PRESENT"
  idx1 <- (nrow(m) - 1L):1
  idx2 <- rep.int(1:(nrow(m) - 1L), idx1)
  idx3 <- sequence(idx1, 2:nrow(m))
  v <- integer(length(idx2))
  
  for (i in 1:ncol(m)) {
    v <- v + (m[idx2, i] & m[idx3, i])
  }
  
  test_self <- matrix(nrow = nrow(test_PAV), ncol = nrow(test_PAV))
  test_self[lower.tri(test_self)] <- v
  diag(test_self) <- rowSums(m)
  return(test_self)
}
```

It took about 40 seconds on my machine and a small fraction of my 8 GB of RAM.

```
system.time(test_self2 <- fCommonVec2(test_PAV))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   36.52    0.24   36.76
```

Comment: I tried the Vector solution on my real dataframe which is 267 rows by 113000 columns and the memory of 32Gb was not enough to calculate it. I'm using R on an HPC cluster where I can ask for more memory and CPU options. What do you think I should allocate to allow for this computation? Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: My guess is you're just shy of the memory you'd need. Splitting the comparison in half should do it. I'll take a look when I get time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as this is the fastest algorithm to create the result!

Comment: @ibozanova FYI this solution only computes the lower triangle of the combination (which is good), so to compare timings you'd have to compare with the combination variant ;)

Comment: @mozway combination was very fast as well but since it didn't report A/A I had to work on getting that in. I believe both answers are very brilliant. Thank you both for your time :) Very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes there is a bit of extra work to compute A/A and transform the half matrix into a full one, let me now if you need it at some point and I could add it.

Comment: @ibozanova, would you be able to get an Rcpp solution to work on the cluster? That would be faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: @ibozanova See the update with a memory-friendly version that maxed out at ~1GB of RAM.

Comment: The updated version does really make a difference, I was able to compute it on my computer without connecting to HPC. But I will also give it a go to the Rcpp solution.

Comment: This question might be good to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32810274/9463489

Answer (score 2):

First, let's keep only the PRESENT genes and build a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of present genes per row:

```
s = (
 df.where(df.eq('PRESENT'))
   .stack()
   .reset_index(level=1)
   .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(frozenset)
)

# 1    (gene3, gene1)
# 2    (gene2, gene1)
# 3    (gene3, gene2)
# Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Now we can get the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (or, to be faster the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)) to build the expected dataframe from the length of the [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of genes set:

```
from itertools import product

out = (
 pd.Series({(i,j): len(a.intersection(b))
           for (i,a),(j,b) in  product(zip(s.index, s), repeat=2)})
   .unstack()
)

#    1  2  3
# 1  2  1  1
# 2  1  2  1
# 3  1  1  2
```

combinations are faster as only 1 of A/B or B/A is computed, and also not A/A:

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (
 pd.Series({(i,j): len(a.intersection(b))
           for (i,a),(j,b) in combinations(zip(s.index, s), r=2)})
   .unstack()
)

#      2    3
# 1  1.0  1.0
# 2  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It definitely works much faster than the initial code.  In the meantime, I have come up with my own similar version

I `sed` the PRESENT with 1 and LOST with 0 imported as new dataframe then

```R
for (rowInQuestion in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
  for (rowBeingComparedTo in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
    pavSelfSimilarity[rowInQuestion,rowBeingComparedTo] <- sum(pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowInQuestion,]*pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowBeingComparedTo,])
  }
}
```

Comment: @ibozanova Great! Maybe you want to post your version here as answer as well ;)

Comment: Yes, I just did!

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with another solution as well if anyone wants to use it;

Instead of using a dataframe with 'PRESENT' and 'LOST' I have used `sed` to transfer them into 1's and 0's.

```sh
sed -i '' 's/PRESENT/1/g' pav-matrix.binary.txt
sed -i '' 's/LOST/0/g' pav-matrix.binary.txt
```

Then used this binary matrix to compare every product of each row's and get the sum of the product array.

```
for (rowInQuestion in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
  for (rowBeingComparedTo in 1:nrow(pavMatrix_transposeBinary)){
    pavSelfSimilarity[rowInQuestion,rowBeingComparedTo] <- sum(pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowInQuestion,]*pavMatrix_transposeBinary[rowBeingComparedTo,])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `for` loop with `awk` should work.

```
for i in {2..4}; do 
   for j in {2..4};do 
      tmp=$(awk '{print $'$i',$'$j'}' input |sed 1d|awk '$1==$2 {print}'|grep -c "PRESENT");echo -en "$tmp\t"
   done 
   echo -en "\n" 
done >> test_self
```

Output:

```
2       1       1
1       2       1
1       1       2
```

You might have to add the headers by yourself, the order should be the same.

Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you @reddy7 this solution definitely works for the problem. It was not memory-consuming.